# Rails Fullcalendar set certain events editable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Fullcalendar in Rails.  The following code from the event model creates the json for Fullcalendar events.

I want the event editable: true if the event.maxsynch = "N"

This is the code:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  {
      :id => self.id,
      :title => "#{self.workorder.wonum} #{self.title} #{self.hours}",
      :description => self.description || "",
      :start => starts_at.rfc822,
      :end => ends_at.rfc822,
      :allDay => self.all_day,
      :recurring => false,
      :editable => false if self.maxsynch == "N" :true,
      :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id),
      :color => "blue",
      :backgroundColor => "blue",
     :borderColor => "black",
     :textColor  => "white"
  }

end
```

The line :editable => false if self.maxsynch == "N" :true, is wrong.

How can I fix it?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are trying to use is called a Conditional or Ternary Operator. "If a condition is true do A, otherwise, do B."

You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Ruby

So that line should read something like

```
:editable => (self.maxsynch == "N" ? true : false),
```

But, if all you are doing is returning true or false, you shouldn't have to use a conditional operator at all. You should just have to pass the evaluated expression.

```
:editable => (self.maxsynch == "N"),
```

It will return true, if the statement is true, otherwise it will return false. If you need it to have the opposite behavior, just add an ! to the beginning of the statement and it will reverse the logic.

Comment: Follow-up question = How would I set the `:color => "blue"` if `(self.maxsynch == "N"),` and yellow if not?  So, the user could tell which ones are editable?

Comment: So that's a better use for a conditional operator. You can just do `:color => (self.maxsynch == "N" ? "blue" : "yellow"),`